# Span shifts its following content CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a Find and Replace. Because of technical restrictions I can't directly wrap the find results in "span" to highlight them. So I have to duplicate the "div" with the content in the background, putting it invisible, and then highlight the results. The issue is that when wrapping my results in "span", With some letters which takes some place like "T" or "P" it shifts the next "span" from 1px and so shifts the whole content

```
<div class="highlight" style="position: absolute;color: transparent;line-height: inherit;">
    <span class="findReplace_marker">Toto</span>
    o SOLD OUT
    <span class="findReplace_marker">Toto</span>
    <span class="findReplace_marker">Toto</span>
    <span class="findReplace_marker">Toto</span>
    <span class="findReplace_marker">Toto</span>
    <span class="findReplace_marker">Toto</span>
    <span class="findReplace_marker focused">Toto</span>
</div>


.findReplace_marker {
        background-color: #fdf0c3;
}
```

Examples:

[image: Example]

[image: Example]

[image: Example]

[image: Working Example]

Comment: Add code please

Comment: You have an additional character that im guessing isnt supposed to be there?  "o SOLD OUT" should be just "SOLD OUT" no? Also if you have extra space its because there is extra whitespace between the two spans that SOLD OUT is between as you have returned them on a new line.

Comment: "o SOLD OUT" is correct since i'm searching for toto and the sentence is "Totoo SOLD OUT". So it takes Toto and it remains "o SOLD OUT".
And its not about the new line, as you can see on the screens the shift begins when 2 <span> are next to each other

Comment: im really sorry im not sure what your trying to say. The content of a span cant leave it and enter another, it can overlap but not leave an element like that and i cant see anything wrong with the images you provided as all the text present is present in the same order in your spans...

Comment: The problem is not the content of the spans. As you can see on the screens, the two div contain the same sentence, however, the one with the highlight is shifted, takes more space. This comes from the fact that when there is a "T" just after a </span> the span "pushes" the "T" and so shifts the whole thing